# Java exception when adding to map

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception

Not sure what is wrong...it should work or maybe am missing something? the following is the code:

```
public class TestOracleMap implements java.io.Serializable{
static TreeMap<String, Integer> map;
static TreeMap<String, Integer> localMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

public static void StoreMapInDB(TreeMap<String, Integer> map) throws
        IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    try {
  PreparedStatement insertMap = null;
  //String insertString = "INSERT INTO TESTMAP(ID, MPFIELD) VALUES (1, ?)";
  Connection con=null;
  con.setAutoCommit(false);
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oXXX",
    "XXX",
    "XXX");

  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
  out.writeObject(map);
  out.close();

  byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
  PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("insert into  

  TESTMAP(ID,MAPFIELD)values(?,?)");
  prepareStatement.setLong(1, 1);
  prepareStatement.setBinaryStream(2, new ByteArrayInputStream(buf), buf.length);



 // insertMap.executeUpdate();
  con.commit();
    } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try{
    DateTime today = new DateTime();
    int x = 1;
    map.put("Hello!", x);
    StoreMapInDB(map);
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.err.print(ioe);
    }
}
}
```

the error is in the line in the main method that is:

```
map.put("Hello!", x);
```

it gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at core.smd.classes.TestOracleMap.main(TestOracleMap.java:61)
 Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Whee did you initialize "map"?  Looks null to me.

Comment: Did you init 'map' somewhere? I see only initialization of localMap...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you never instantiate `map`. You declare it here

```
static TreeMap<String, Integer> map;
```

but when you use it here it is still `null` giving you the `NullPointerException`.

```
map.put("Hello!", x);
```

If you do this before

```
map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

it should run fine.

Comment: cool that doesn't return the null anymore...now the line where it says connection con = null; then I do con.setAutoCommit(false);
the thing here is it is returning null but clearly because I set it null in the line before. if I dont, it says it is not initialized. anyway out?

Comment: duffymo gives you the solution for the con problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Where did you initialize "map"?  Looks null to me.

Change this line:

```
static TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

You declare this and set it to null, but I don't see where you use it.

```
PreparedStatement insertMap = null;
```

You've got more heartache ahead here:

```
Connection con=null;
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oXXX",
    "XXX",
    "XXX");
  con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Move the autoCommit down until after you get the connection from the driver manager.

You're serializing the Map to INSERT it into the database?  That's not normalized.  A normalized schema would have a row per entry.

The more I read your code, the less sense it makes.  Good luck.

Comment: I know the code is messy but the map after testing the table solution instead seemed better for this purpose. I am attempting this for the first time so yeh it might not look good. Thanks though :)

Comment: maybe its being serialised as a caching mechanism or as a way to maintain state. See Fowler's Enterprise Patterns book about different reasons for doing that.

Comment: Fair enough.  Good point, Ilan.  The OP just needs to realize that it's not normalized.  The implication is that s/he won't be able to search on individual values in the Map.  Storing and retrieving are "all or none" operations.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize `map` to anything, hence it is `null`. You'll need to assign a valid `TreeMap<String, Integer>` to it somewhere, like for instance on line 2 when you declare it, use:

```
static TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

the variable map is never initialized, only declared in the constructor.

```
map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

you only declare map,but not initialize it

```
static TreeMap<String, Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(); // <-- in your code, you're not constructing it
static TreeMap<String, Integer> localMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You r initializing a variable Connection con = null;
then u r setting con.setAutoCommit(false)..
Without creating object for that how can u set auto commit for that?

Answer (score 0):

you did initialize map object as you initialized localMap object at declaration just check that